# Do invertible fractional ideals have a unique decomposition into primes?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I thought about the question in the title for a ring that is not a Dedekind domain (here, the unique decomposition is a well-known theorem and also characterizes Dedekind domains!) but only a one-dimensional noetherian integral domain.

The following is the motivation: In a Dedekind domain, every fractional ideal is invertible.

Therefore, my idea is that actually the invertibility of such a fractional ideal makes a unique prime decomposition possible.

Is this true? If yes, how could one proof this?